# Are printing questions in scope on GD?

Tags: discussion

I was curious to know if printing questions in regards to how the design turns out on topic here and what would possibly render the question off-topic?  I know I shouldn't ask about equipment but if I wanted to ask a question in regards to the type of median used for a desired design look on topic?

Comment: Of course they are!

Comment: @Scott: Maybe you could argument your opinion? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think any sort of prepress questions are fine here. As an example: "***How should I set up a two color silkscreen print with trapping?***" makes sense to me to be within the scope of Graphic Design.

However, technical printing questions are their own realm and don't fit here. For example: "***How can I achieve tight registration for a multicolor silkscreen job that has trapping?***" would stick out as something beyond the scope of GD.

To address your example specifically (type of medium for a desired design look)—that sounds on topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think printing questions are perfectly fine as long as they have a bit of GD in them. So asking about printing issues/details that arise from or can be affected by graphics design are okay. E.g. **How to do GD for ABCD with regard to printing issues EFGH?**.

Purely printing questions are a bit offtopic IMO. E.g. **How to load paper into bin to achieve best alignment?** or **In which order to silk-screen colors?**. But still they are connected with GD and provide some in-depth view on the process and IMHO they could be tolerated.